# как сделать плавный скролл к элементу на jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня такая проблема: нужно написать скрипт на jquery - скролл к элелменту. Но все варианты, которые я находил, при нажатии по ссылке сначала перескакивают на начало страницы и от начала уже скролят до нужного элемента. Мне же необходим скролл и вверх, и вниз сразу от того места, где я нахожусь, независимо в какой части страницы я нахожусь, без перескакивания в начало страницы. Иными словами, нужен код который работает безоговорочно по точно такой же логике, что и этот. Но данный код написан на чистом js, когда мне нужно jq. Заранее спасибо!

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"').forEach(link => {

link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let href = this.getAttribute('href').substring(1);

    const scrollTarget = document.getElementById(href);

    const topOffset = document.querySelector('.scrollto').offsetHeight;
    // const topOffset = 0; // если не нужен отступ сверху 
    const elementPosition = scrollTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    const offsetPosition = elementPosition - topOffset;

    window.scrollBy({
        top: offsetPosition,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
});
```

});

Comment: И где здесь jQuery?

Comment: а вы свой проект делаете или подписались кому то сделать?

Comment: Т.е., код у вас есть, с ним проблем нет и вы хотите, что бы кто то за вас переписал код на jQuery(зачем, чем вас js не устраивает?)? Конечно, может и найдутся альтруисты, но лучше сами попробуйте переписать, а возникнут сложности, приходите с конкретной проблемой, поможем, чем сможем.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/scroll-to-an-element-with-jquery